# How to define nested SQL statement to return calculated value?

Tags: sql, ms-access, nested

The problem is as follows. I have the following SQL statement:

```
// SQL statement for ms access 2010
SELECT 
    ID, SUM(fund_assets) AS Sum_FV, COUNT(*) AS DataCount, 
    (Sum_FV / DataCount) AS Result
FROM 
    V_Assets_L12
WHERE 
    Datum >= DATEADD("m", -12, #6/2/2017#) 
    AND Datum <= #6/2/2017# 
    AND ID = 325
GROUP BY 
    ID
ORDER BY 
    ID;
```

The result is correct for `ONE` ID! But I need a list of all existing IDs of V_Assets_L12. So that my first idea was to define a nested sql statement as follows:

```
SELECT 
    ID, SUM(fund_assets) AS Sum_FV, COUNT(*) AS DataCount, 
    (Sum_FV / DataCount) AS Result
FROM 
    V_Assets_L12
WHERE 
    Datum >= DATEADD("m", -12, #6/2/2017#) 
    AND Datum <= #6/2/2017# 
    AND ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID
               FROM V_Assets_L12
               ORDER BY ID ASC)
GROUP BY 
    ID
ORDER BY 
    ID;
```

But this doesn't work for me. What did I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the condition in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(fund_assets) AS Sum_FV, COUNT(*) AS DataCount,
       (Sum_FV / DataCount) AS Result
FROM V_Assets_L12
WHERE Datum >= DateAdd("m", -12, #6/2/2017#) And
      Datum <= #6/2/2017#
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: What is if I want to select 3 IDs e.g. 325, 466 and 30014. How can I solve this issue?